# Angular CLI cannot find modules that are clearly in workspace

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I got this error when I deleted a component and recreated it in the CLI with the same name and folder structure.

`ng g component <mycomponentname>`

As soon as I did this, the CLI started throwing errors saying that it can't find modules that are clearly there and were left untouched. These are simple classes and services, not NPM packages or third party libraries.

Is there a way that I can build the project completely clean? Or a way to force a fresh cache or something?

Comment: add the error please

Comment: is your module containing `mycomponentname` still there?

Comment: @ABOS yes and it is properly referenced in `app.module.ts` as well

Comment: you could try to rebuild it with `ng build --delete-output-path`

Answer (score 0):

May some import failed, please check app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple modules you have to specify which one you're adding the component too. For example:

```
Ng g c "componentname" --module app
```

if your module is called app